# C++ no implicit conversions when forwarding arguments deduced from function pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm trying to produce a smart proxy function, so that arguments are forwarded as given.

Here's the code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

void func(int foo) {
    std::cout<<foo<<"\n";
}

template<typename... ARGS>
void proxy( void(*callback)(ARGS...), ARGS&&... args) {
    callback( std::forward<ARGS>(args)... );
}

int main() {
    proxy( func, 17 );
    int foo = 17;
    proxy( func, foo );
}
```

I was hoping that by letting the template resolution figure out `func`'s arguments, I'll have proxy with the signature `void proxy( void(*)(int), int );`. As such, it should accept both the first invocation (int is a rvalue) or second (int is a lvalue).

In reality, the above program fails with:

```
so.cpp:16:5: error: no matching function for call to 'proxy'
    proxy( func, foo );
    ^~~~~
so.cpp:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'ARGS' (<int> vs. <int &>)
void proxy( void(*callback)(ARGS...), ARGS&&... args) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I.e. - failure to implicitly convert from `int &` to `int`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are two places to deduce `ARGS` from. Function template argument deduction is always done for each function parameter/argument pair individually and then combined.

> **[temp.deduct.type]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#2) In some cases, the deduction is done using a single set of
>   types `P` and `A`, in other cases, there will be a set of
>   corresponding types `P` and `A`. Type deduction is done independently
>   for each `P`/`A` pair, and the deduced template argument values are
>   then combined. If type deduction cannot be done for any `P`/`A` pair,
>   or if for any pair the deduction leads to more than one possible set
>   of deduced values, or if different pairs yield different deduced
>   values, or if any template argument remains neither deduced nor
>   explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails. The type of a
>   type parameter is only deduced from an array bound if it is not
>   otherwise deduced.

Since the function parameter pack contains forwarding references, it will deduce either `int&` or `int` depending on the value category of the corresponding argument. While the function type (from which deduction also occurs) can only lead to the deduction of `int`. For lvalues, the two deductions disagree, and so substitution fails.

Failure to substitute is not an error, it just removes the overload from the candidate set. But in your case, it's the only candidate, so it becomes a hard error.

So you need to make the two deductions independent, this means two packs. That will still gives us an `int&` vs. `int`, but we can add a SFIANE check that verifies the types after removing the reference. This should give the desired behavior.

```
template<typename... ARGS1, typename... ARGS2>
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<ARGS1>, std::decay_t<ARGS2>> && ...)>
proxy( void(*callback)(ARGS1...), ARGS2&&... args) {
    callback( std::forward<ARGS2>(args)... );
}
```

The return type uses a fold expression to verify each pair of arguments, but only after both have their cv-qualifiers and references type removed (that's what `decay_t` is for, among other things). If the check passes, then `enable_if_t` exists and is `void` (the default `::type` of `enable_if`).

Here it is [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af241daf627b7fb3).

If however you decide that you wish to support convertibility, the above check can be amended to use `std::is_convertible_v` instead of `std::is_same_v`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the two locations that the ARGS template arguments allows different types for each variadic expansion (and each individual argument).

You need to make the arguments ( eg. ARGS&&... args) dependent or static cast. You can do a tedious method which I believe retains perfect forwarding, thats shown last because its pretty verbose.

This method is my favorite as it plays really well with intelisense.
This method doesn't "perfect forward" in some cases but it will almost always be the same so maybe its good for you :):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func (int foo)
{
    std::cout << foo << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
struct Mirror
{
    using type = T;
};

template < typename ... FunctionArgs >
void proxy (void (*callback) (FunctionArgs ...), typename Mirror<FunctionArgs>::type ... args)
{
    callback (args ...);
}

int main ()
{
    proxy (func, 17);
    int foo = 17;
    proxy (func, foo);
}
```

The static cast method:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func (int foo)
{
    std::cout << foo << "\n";
}

template < typename ... FunctionArgs, typename ... UsedArgs >
void proxy (void (*callback) (FunctionArgs ...), UsedArgs && ... args)
{
    callback (static_cast < FunctionArgs > (args) ...);
}

int main ()
{
    proxy (func, 17);
    int foo = 17;
    proxy (func, foo);
}
```

Verbose method, this I think retains all the perfect forwarding:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func (int foo)
{
    std::cout << foo << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
struct Mirror
{
    using type = T;
};

template < typename ... FunctionArgs, typename ... UsedArgs >
void proxy (void (*callback) (FunctionArgs ...), UsedArgs && ... args)
{
    callback ([](auto m, auto && a) -> decltype(auto)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<decltype(a)>)
        {
            return std::forward<decltype(a)>(a);
        }
        else
        {
            return static_cast<typename decltype(m)::type>(a);
        }
    }( Mirror<UsedArgs>{}, std::forward<FunctionArgs>(args) ) ... );
}

int main ()
{
    proxy (func, 17);
    int foo = 17;
    proxy (func, foo);
}
```

Comment: If this compiles it looks like a better approach. The problem thus lies with the fact that proxy never does perfect forwarding, it must always be passed an rvalue (int), as with std::move. Remember : for perfect forwarding you can't use the template type arg(s) with multiple signatures : here it is ARGS mixed with ARGS&&, so you're not forwarding perfectly

Comment: Exactly right!
Most of the time I believe it would do copy elision. But I haven't yet tested that theory.

Comment: You could do a conditional std::forward with if constexpr inside an immediately invoked inline lambda to do this perfectly. So for any reference type you forward otherwise static_cast to the value type.

Comment: @Arne J I've shown the verbose version which I think does all the forwarding correctly, we might need to add some additional arguments to the lambda like an explicit return type.